# Detecting File changes - Patching System

Tags: c#, wpf, patch

I'm working an application that manages the launching, licencing and patching of multiple other in-house applications. We call this portal.

There are a number of reasons for using portal, which i wont get into here, but patching in a limited bandwidth situation is one of them.

My current plan is as follows:

1. Store the installed version in a .xml file (this is updated on a successful update)
2. Check the stored value against the latest release version
3. If different, download a .xml manifest of the files in the latest version
4. Compare the downloaded manifest with the local files
5. Download only those files that have changed

My question is, what would be a reasonable and reliable way to check each file for changes, would a simple MD5 of each file be sufficient, or would i need something more robust?

Comment: MD5 is sufficient for this purpose (to tell if a file has been changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In may opinion a MD5 is sufficient, I've been using to compare files and it's pretty good.

Also, it's the common way used by websites, most of them relies only on MD5 checksum to compare files. Besides you can search on Google and find applications, tools and lot of stuff related to the topic.